# Load a single field of the object in realm

Tags: android, realm

Suppose I have a Book object(id, name, author).

Suppose I have a big list of books, is it possible to retrieve only the names of these books without retrieving the entire objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose I have a big list of books, is it possible to retrieve only the names of these books without retrieving the entire objects?

Sure, see:

```
private RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Book>> listener = (results) -> {
    adapter.updateData(results);
};

RealmResults<Book> books;

void blah() {
    books = realm.where(Book.class).findAllAsync();
    books.addChangeListener(listener);
}
```

And

```
public class MyAdapter extends ___Adapter {
   ...

   public class ViewHolder /* ... */ {
       public void bind(Book book) {
           bookName.setText(book.getName());
       }
   }
}
```

The reason this would work is that while RealmResults evaluates "how to access the given objects", you actually load only the name of the book, by calling `book.getName()`.

Basically, managed RealmObjects are lazily accessed, and Realm itself only loads given object properties when that given property's accessor is called: in this case, `book.getName()`.

---

As for getting a `List<String>`, not really. That would read the property from every single object.

Comment: Maybe instead of passing the book to the adapter I'll just add the name to the list?
Also, is it necessary to perform this in "addChangeListener"? why not a normal query?

Comment: This is a normal query, an asynchronous one anyways. If you extract `List<String>` by iterating over the list, then you'll read every String eagerly instead of when you access the object's property. Whether that is what you want or not is down to your personal requirements, ofc. Although I would not advise doing that on the UI thread. If you were using my library `monarchy` then you'd do a `findAllMappedWithChanges` and receive a `LiveData<List<String>>`.

Comment: Yes, I want a full list to operate on, so would iterating over results load only the names and not the whole object?
Thanks!

Comment: Technically yes.